# PHP double quote string issue

Tags: php

I am trying to put my variable's value inside the line:

```
$email .= "What do you need the container for?: $json['purpose']";
```

However I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Try enclosing the variable with {} - like - {$json['purpose']}

Comment: You need to show more since it is using `$json` in it

Comment: show us the value of `var_dump($json['purpose']);`

Comment: Thanks {} worked.

Comment: More Learn at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution one (Enclosing with {}):

```
$email .= "What do you need the container for?: {$json['purpose']}";
```

Solution two (escape):

```
$email .= "What do you need the container for?: ".$json['purpose']."";
```

Both of them work :)